# Luigi event handler when no task is run because no missing dependencies

Tags: luigi

I am familiar with the Luigi event handling mechanism, and I have  implemented a pipeline for which a success email is sent when the pipeline completes successfully.
I would like to know how to trigger an event when a task has already been run and hence the task is no longer re-run. Case in point - my job gets triggered when a new dated file shows up on a daily schedule. On Sunday, no new file shows up and luigi produces this output:

```
 ===== Luigi Execution Summary =====

 Scheduled 1 tasks of which:
* 1 present dependencies were encountered:
- 1 XXXXRunner(...)

 Did not run any tasks
 This progress looks :) because there were no failed tasks or missing 
external dependencies
```

For a successful run, I would normally trigger an email as follows:

```
 @SomeTaskRunner.event_handler(luigi.Event.SUCCESS)
 def send_success_email():
 ....
```

But in the case when no task is run because all dependencies have been met, how do I trigger the event handler ?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out.

I need to use this event handler:

```
 @SomeTaskRunner.event_handler(luigi.Event.DEPENDENCY_PRESENT)
```